# How to add a contact using their Skype ID?

Tags: windows-7, skype

How to add a contact using their Skype ID?

When I do:

[image]

and look for the Skype ID `dom_marshall`
I don't have one but several results:

[image]

I use Skype on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: You don't.  Skype ID's have been retired.  They were retired over 2 years ago.  So that person has a Microsoft Account and you can find them that way.

Answer (score 3):

**Codepen**

https://codepen.io/mklepaczewski/pen/JOeexg

**Original answer**

Create a small HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- Replace {skype_id} with dom_marshall -->
        <a href="skype:{skype_id}?chat">Launch Skype</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Open it with your browser of choice, click on the link to launch Skype and initiate a chat with given Skype ID. You might need to integrate Skype with your browser though.

Comment: To make it even easier, you can type the URL "skype:{skype_id}?chat" in a browser of your choice, and it will open Skype.

Answer (score 1):

The one you are looking for is the first one with the eagle. To figure out the actual skype id right click them and click view profile. This will show you the actual skype ID.

Comment: Thanks, but it's a bit tedious to have to right click on each result. Does the contact with the matching actual skype ID also appear first in the result list?

Comment: That takeover by M$ is certainly a disaster. Thank god i still have sorting by skype ID in my version, but for how long???

Comment: I would expect it to but I can't say for sure. It has in the past for myself though.

Comment: As of now matching Skype ID does NOT appear first in the list of results. I had to view several profiles before finding the right one. People with even a bit common names cannot be found reasonably fast this way.